# What is the simplest way to draw the solution of a simultaneous inequalities using PSTricks?

Tags: pstricks

## Objective

I want to draw a region in Cartesian coordinate system that satisfies a set of inequalities. How to do this in the simplest way?

[image]

[image]

## Minimal Code

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\pspicture*[showgrid=false](-1,-4)(3,1)
\pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red,opacity=0.25,linestyle=none]%
(0,0)(0,-3)(2,0)
\psset{linewidth=0.4pt}
\psaxes[arrows=<->](0,0)(-0.5,-3.5)(2.5,0.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\psplot[algebraic]{-0.25}{2.25}{1.5*x-3}
\psset{linecolor=red,linewidth=1.5pt}
\psline[linestyle=dashed](0,-3)
\psline[linestyle=dashed](2,0)
\psline(2,0)(0,-3)
\rput[tl](1,-1.5){$y=\frac{3}{2}x-3$}
\endpspicture

\end{document}
```

## Edit 1

Actually I can do this by finding the "critical" points **MANUALLY** and use them as the parameters for `\psline`. Put the lines into `\pscustom` and set the fill color. Done.

But if there is a more efficient approach, please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see, you want to clip the area. This is easy:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=2}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-4)(3,1)
  \psclip{%
    \pscustom[linestyle=none]{%
      \psline(0,-4)
      \psplot[algebraic]{-1}{2.25}{1.5*x-3}
      \psline(3,0)(0,0)
    }
  }
    \psframe[fillstyle=vlines,linestyle=none](0,-4)(3,0)
  \endpsclip
\psaxes[arrows=<->](0,0)(-0.5,-3.5)(2.5,0.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\psplot[algebraic]{-1}{2.25}{1.5*x-3}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Clipping does the calculation of the intermediate points by default.

[image]

Comment: There is no `IfTE` in `pst-plot`.

Comment: @xport: hm maybe pstricks-add. Cannot really remember

Comment: @xport: see edited answer

Answer (score 4):

For a more complicated case, we have to find the intersection points first as follows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-eucl,graphicx}

\def\f#1{#1 1 add}
\def\g#1{#1 neg 3 div 2 add}
\def\h#1{#1 neg 3 add}

\def\getX#1{\psGetNodeCenter{#1} #1.x}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture*}[showgrid](-1,-2)(4,3)
    \psset{PointName=none,PointSymbol=none}
    \pstInterFF{\f{x}}{\g{x}}{0}{A}%
    \pstInterFF{\g{x}}{\h{x}}{0}{B}%
    \begin{psclip}{
    \pscustom[linestyle=none]{
        \psline(!0 \f{0})
        \psplot{0}{\getX{A}}{\f{x}}
        \psplot{\getX{A}}{\getX{B}}{\g{x}}
        \psplot{\getX{B}}{2.5}{\h{x}}
        \psline(2.5,0)
        \closepath}}
        \rput(1.5,0.5){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}
    \end{psclip}
    \psplot{-1}{4}{\f{x}}
    \psplot{-1}{4}{\g{x}}
    \psplot{-1}{4}{\h{x}}
    \psline(2.5,-2)(2.5,3)
    \psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptscriptstyle]{->}(0,0)(-0.75,-1.75)(3.5,2.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\end{pspicture*}  


\end{document}
```

### Latest update

Using infix notation for the sake of your convenience.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-eucl,graphicx}

\def\f{(x+1)}
\def\g{(-x/3+2)}
\def\h{(-x+3)}
\def\x#1{N-#1.x}

\pstVerb{/I2P {AlgParser cvx exec} def}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture*}[algebraic,saveNodeCoors,PointName=none,PointSymbol=none](-1,-2)(4,3)
    \pstInterFF{\f I2P}{\g I2P}{0}{A}
    \pstInterFF{\g I2P}{\h I2P}{0}{B}
    \begin{psclip}{%
    \pscustom[linestyle=none]
        {
        \psline(*0 {\f})
        \psplot{0}{\x{A}}{\f}
        \psplot{\x{A}}{\x{B}}{\g}
        \psplot{\x{B}}{2.5}{\h}
        \psline(2.5,0)
        \closepath
        }}
        \rput(1.5,0.5){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}
    \end{psclip}
    \psplot{-1}{4}{\f}
    \psplot{-1}{4}{\g}
    \psplot{-1}{4}{\h}
    \psline(2.5,-2)(2.5,3)
    \psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptscriptstyle]{->}(0,0)(-0.75,-1.75)(3.5,2.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\end{pspicture*}  

\end{document}
```