# includegraphics: How to check if PDF/PNG are transparent?

Tags: graphics, pdftex, pdf, transparency

I am trying to generate PDF/A-1 compliant documents, in which transparency is not allowed. I would like to check, if included PDF and PNG images have transparency.

Is there a TeX way to check this? Otherwise, what is the proper way to change the `\includegraphics` command to call external tools to check this?

---

Edit: External tools for checking transparency:

For **PNGs**, `ImageMagik`'s `identify`  does the job nicely. It displays `[s]rgba` when there is an alpha channel (otherwise it's `rgb`):

```
# identify -format '%[channels]' Transparent.png 
srgba
```

Even better:

```
# identify -format %A Transparent.png 
True
```

For **PDFs**, this is more complicated (see eg [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pdfnet-sdk/Ke75f9qBGYc)): There are as graphical style attributes fill opacity (`/ca`) or stroke opacities (`/CA`) below a value of 1.0, or there is a soft mask (`\SMask`), or there is a transparency page group defined (`/S /Transparency`). `grep` expression:

```
grep -aE -e '/[Cc][Aa] +0?\.[0-9]' -e '/SMask' -e '/S /Transparency' *.pdf
```

I bet it is somehow possible to check with `gs`, [but I did not find it so far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006602/check-with-ghostscript-whether-a-pdf-has-transparent-objects).

Comment: For png, I think that `file` gives you this information. Doesn't it output RGB for non-transparent and RGBA for transparent? Or I'm sure `convert` can give you this information if you go through its (many) options!

Comment: A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Tobi: I'll do that. cfr: Thanks for the comment, `identify` does the job.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no "Tex way" to check graphics. That is, during compilation of the document, it does not look into the image code to tell whether a partiular image has transparency, or RGB or CMYK, has a color profile, or anything like that. External programs must be used in advance. It would be nice if Tex could invoke an external command-line program and be able to throw an error (in Tex) if the image is wrong, according to some crieteria. File that under "Wish List."

Answer (score 3):

I would use ghostscript to remove the transparency once the pdf is generated, using

`gs -o converted.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dHaveTransparency=false input_file.pdf`

Answer (score 1):

If you are generating your pdf document from the tex document at the command line then any of the previous suggestions are viable. To decrease typing at the command line you can write a makefile to handle the transparency checks and then generate the pdf.

If you really want to do everything from within the tex document you can try the [bashful](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bashful) package or the `\write18` command as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/92691/is-it-possible-to-call-external-programs-from-latex).

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'built in' way to check if an image is transparent. As such, you will need to pre-process your images either as part of the TeX run (using shell escape) or before it. Doing things during the TeX run is going to be more awkward here as it has to happen every time you do the rung and requires a lowering of your security settings. In any case, the appropriate tools for removing transparency are off-topic for us.