# Is it possible to run a script in e.g. Python in a LaTeX .cls?

Tags: package-writing, scripts

For a package I'm writing, it would be very handy to use some programmed scripts, for example written in Python. Is there a way how I could add these to my `.cls` file?

And if not, what is the usual way to add scripts to a `.cls`?

Comment: Most people use Lua and Lua(La)TeX if they want to do that kind of scripting, but there are alternatives. Have you tried [PythonTeX](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex)?

Comment: @frabjous I usually use XeLaTeX. I still wonder, though: There must be some scripting for most packages, even if they just use simple (PDF)LaTeX, no?

Comment: @TiMauzi Yes, they (painstakingly) did the programming in TeX. (TeX is a terrible programming language in my opinion, even though I can write it now...)

Comment: If you can limit your .cls to Lua only, just use LuaLaTeX. Alternatively, if you can limit yourself to always enable shell-escape and doesn't need macros to be expandable then that one can be used as well.

Comment: TeX itself is Turing complete, and you can "script" with it directly if you like; packages like [expl3](https://ctan.org/pkg/expl3?lang=en) make it easier. You can even call external programs with write18; see, e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/92691/is-it-possible-to-call-external-programs-from-latex). But I can definitely see why someone might prefer Python, and that may include you. Should be do-able either way. Which do you prefer?

Comment: @user202729 Interesting, I didn't know that TeX itself is a programming language by itself already. I assumed people just use it to call other programs in "normal" programming languages. Can you recommend some tutorials or starting points, if I want to learn more about TeX coding?

Comment: There's https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming/27589#27589 / https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/where-do-i-find-out-how-a-command-environment-is-defined/621577#621577 (disclaimer, the second one is my answer) I have to warn that TeX is a **very inconvenient** programming language though.

Comment: @TiMauzi if  your users use `--shell-escape` commandline option then you can run any command from within your class including deleting all their files. For good reason users are strongly advised _not_ to use `--shell-escape` on random tex code they find on the internet, so you can do this if you really need it (eg the  `minted` package uses the python pygments library for code syntax highlighting) but be aware that it severely limits the usability of your class.

Comment: @user202729 that is not how you spell **enjoyable**